# How can I update a Gridview with 2 parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm new to this and maybe doing things wrong. I'm trying to produce a filtered view using 2 different parameters.

When I pass in one parameter my code works

```
           <asp:ListBox ID="ReportListItemsLb" runat="server" DataSourceID="ReportItems" 
    DataTextField="ReportGroupName" DataValueField="ReportGroupId" Height="134px" 
        Width="217px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ReportItems" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WeighBridgeDataConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ReportGroupName, ReportGroupId FROM MonthlyReports.ReportGroups">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ListBox ID="DateLb" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="MainPullBack" DataTextField="Date" DataValueField="Date" 
        Height="106px" Width="218px"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MainPullBack" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WeighBridgeDataConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT distinct MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Date 
        FROM MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT INNER JOIN MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData ON 
        MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.WSDOUTId = MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.WSDOUTId 
        WHERE (MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.ReportGroupId = @reportgroupid) AND (MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Active = 1)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ReportListItemsLb" Name="reportgroupid" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="AllInOneViewGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="AllInOneView">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Waste" HeaderText="Waste" SortExpression="Waste" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" 
                SortExpression="Source" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Destination" HeaderText="Destination" 
                SortExpression="Destination" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data1" HeaderText="Data1" SortExpression="Data1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data2" HeaderText="Data2" SortExpression="Data2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data3" HeaderText="Data3" SortExpression="Data3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data4" HeaderText="Data4" SortExpression="Data4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data5" HeaderText="Data5" SortExpression="Data5" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WSDOUTId" HeaderText="WSDOUTId" 
                SortExpression="WSDOUTId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportGroupId" HeaderText="ReportGroupId" 
                SortExpression="ReportGroupId" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllInOneView" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WeighBridgeDataConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT  MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Date, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Waste,
         MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Source, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Destination, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data1,
          MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data2, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data3, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data4,
           MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data5, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.WSDOUTId, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.ReportGroupId 
           FROM MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT INNER JOIN MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData ON
            MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.WSDOUTId = MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.WSDOUTId 
            WHERE (MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.ReportGroupId = @reportgroupid) AND (MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Active = 1) ">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ReportListItemsLb" Name="reportgroupid" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

But when I add a second parameter to filter by date nothing happens

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ListBox ID="ReportListItemsLb" runat="server" DataSourceID="ReportItems" 
    DataTextField="ReportGroupName" DataValueField="ReportGroupId" Height="134px" 
        Width="217px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ReportItems" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WeighBridgeDataConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ReportGroupName, ReportGroupId FROM MonthlyReports.ReportGroups">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ListBox ID="DateLb" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="MainPullBack" DataTextField="Date" DataValueField="Date" 
        Height="106px" Width="218px"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MainPullBack" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WeighBridgeDataConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT distinct MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Date 
        FROM MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT INNER JOIN MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData ON 
        MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.WSDOUTId = MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.WSDOUTId 
        WHERE (MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.ReportGroupId = @reportgroupid) AND (MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Active = 1)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ReportListItemsLb" Name="reportgroupid" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="AllInOneViewGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="AllInOneView">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Waste" HeaderText="Waste" SortExpression="Waste" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" 
                SortExpression="Source" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Destination" HeaderText="Destination" 
                SortExpression="Destination" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data1" HeaderText="Data1" SortExpression="Data1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data2" HeaderText="Data2" SortExpression="Data2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data3" HeaderText="Data3" SortExpression="Data3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data4" HeaderText="Data4" SortExpression="Data4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data5" HeaderText="Data5" SortExpression="Data5" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WSDOUTId" HeaderText="WSDOUTId" 
                SortExpression="WSDOUTId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportGroupId" HeaderText="ReportGroupId" 
                SortExpression="ReportGroupId" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllInOneView" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WeighBridgeDataConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT  MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Date, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Waste,
         MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Source, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Destination, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data1,
          MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data2, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data3, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data4,
           MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.Data5, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.WSDOUTId, MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.ReportGroupId 
           FROM MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT INNER JOIN MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData ON
            MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.WSDOUTId = MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.WSDOUTId 
            WHERE (MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.ReportGroupId = @reportgroupid) AND (MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUT.Active = 1) and MonthlyReports.ReportWSDOUTData.date=@date">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ReportListItemsLb" Name="reportgroupid" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DateLb" Name="date" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong and help me figure out a way of doing this?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Could you perhaps only show the relevant code and expand your question?

Comment: are you sure that Date parameters are in the same format, it's a DateTime type? If yes, remember that the time implies.

Comment: Gustavo, Yes, when I test it in the query builder It works, but with only one one id number. I'm trying to pass mutiple id's in, as in the first bit of code (which works) I'm so confused as to why. When I'm in SQL and do the statement it also works fine. Im just really new to .net @GustavoFreddo

Comment: @Brissles I have trimmed it down a bit, to my eye i don't know what else would be better to trim. Any help would be greatly recieved.

Comment: <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ReportListItemsLb" Name="reportgroupid"  
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" /> 
is what I have now and it only brings back the report list items, because that is all I'm pass in is that. what i really need is this, but a working version of this <SelectParameters> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ReportListItemsLb" Name="reportgroupid"  
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" /> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DateLb" Name="date"  
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" /> 
        </SelectParameters>

Comment: Would passing the values through to the sql statement with a button help? If so any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

just add the type of the parameter in the aspx:

```
<asp:Parameter ControlID="ReportListItemsLb" Name="reportgroupid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" type="DateTime"></asp:Parameter>
```

Comment: That gets me back to only filtering on report area and now when I click on date nothing else happens. Have I done something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

1.Create a method which will return db null if parameter is not passed in the stored procedure

```
public static object GetDataValue(object o)
{
    if (o == null || String.Empty.Equals(o))
        return DBNull.Value;
    else
        return o;
}
```

2.Create a method which will called the stored procedure and fill the dataset.

```
public DataSet GetFillGvds(string param_1, string param_2) {

try
{
    DataSet oDS = new DataSet();
    SqlParameter[] oParam = new SqlParameter[2];


    oParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@Param1", GetDataValue(param_1));
    oParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@Param1", GetDataValue(param_2));

    oDS = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(DataConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spTest", oParam);
    return oDS;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ErrorMessage = e.Message;
    return null;
}
}
```

Create a dataset to bind data in the gridview. For instance,

```
DataSet FillGvds = new DataSet();
param1FillGvds = "param1";
param2FillGvds = "";
FillGvds = GetFillGvds();// Assuming you have created the method to fill the dataset.
if(FillGvds != null)
{
 if(FillGvds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
  GridView1.Datasource = FillGvds;
  GridView1.DataBind();
  label1.Text = Convert.ToString(FillGvds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
 }
}


In order to pass the db null you query should be like this.
SELECT *(whatever you want) 
FROM YourTableName
WHERE colName1 = COALESCE(@colName1, colName1) AND
colName2 = COALESCE(@colName2,colName2)
```