# Not displaying data in gridview when applying filter to a dataset

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, filter, dataset

My gridview is not displaying data when filter

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn=new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Dynacs.accdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select empname,pass,status from employees", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "emp");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["emp"].Select("status='in'");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

[image: Showing this when executed]

Comment: What `ds.Tables["emp"].Select("status='in'")` returns? Secondly post gridview code from .aspx? Thirdly handle `IsPostBack` on page load, do binding if `IsPostBack` is false.

Comment: Try this out.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834166/how-can-i-update-a-gridview-with-2-parameters/8846694#8846694

Comment: Any thing wrong in this statementGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["emp"].Select("status='in'");

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't GridView.DataSource be set from a DataSet? You're using an array of DataRows.

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select empname,pass,status from employees", conn);
        DataSet ds1=new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds1,"emp");
            var datasource = from r in ds1.Tables["emp"].AsEnumerable()
                             where r.Field<string>("status")=="out"
                             select new{empname=r.Field<String>("empname"),status=r.Field<string>("status")};
            GridView1.DataSource = datasource;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? (presumably, yes as you answered your other question with it). Please elaborate a bit, and don't forget to mark it as accepted when the system permits.