# query dataset using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-dataset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not displaying data in gridview when applying filter to a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890943/not-displaying-data-in-gridview-when-applying-filter-to-a-dataset)

I am having a **Dataset ds** with contents of table **emp** with **ename** , **pass** , **status** as attributes .

> I want to query the **Dataset** uing **LINQ** such that it returns records whose **status** is **"out"**

it worked when used on **datatable** when i use **dataset** data is not displayed

Please tell me how can i achieve this.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Simple use this and convert result to `list`:
First add a reference to `System.Data.Extensions.dll` (where LINQ over DataSet support is implemented)

```
// Fill the DataSet.
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable orders = ds.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

var query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<string>("status") == "out"
    select order;

yourGridView.DataSource= query.ToList();
yourGridView.DataBind();
```

You can check this also:
[Binding LINQ query to DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393223/binding-linq-query-to-datagridview)

Comment: data not displayed while using the above query

Comment: can you share your code to understand the problem.. this should work if you doing everything in correct way..

Comment: check your gridview markup for problem. if your code behind is written correct at particule event of asp.net page life cycle..

Comment: Hi Niranjan i want to use dataset only.please see the code i had added and suggest me how can i use attributes directly like r.status or r.empname .Thank you

Comment: try to add `.ToList()` to `datasouce`.. and before this check result IEnumerableList contain values or not??

Answer (score 0):

```
   var query = from e in DS1.emp

            where e.status == "out"


            select e;



dataGridView1.DataSource = query.AsDataView();
```

Comment: It will give compilation error "DS1.emp", you can not use Dataset as Datacontext. Instead AsEnumerable() Method will work here.

Answer (score 0):

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select empname,pass,status from employees", conn);
        DataSet ds1=new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds1,"emp");
            var datasource = from r in ds1.Tables["emp"].AsEnumerable()
                             where r.Field<string>("status")=="out"
                             select new{empname=r.Field<String>("empname"),status=r.Field<string>("status")};
            GridView1.DataSource = datasource;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```